# Join two tables in MySQL with random rows from the second

Tags: mysql, join, random

I have two tables

The first with only 5 rows

The second with 800 rows

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) t2
```

But I'm getting 5 rows from the first table for each result of the second table.

I don't need a condition when joining, I just want 5 random results from the second table to join the 5 results from the first.

Example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|table1 (always with same order)| table2(random order) |
--------------------------------------------------------
    item1                       |       item4
    item2                       |       item2 
    item3                       |       item5 
    item4                       |       item1
    item5                       |       item3
```

Comment: Ok, so actually you just want **one** field from each table, not `*`

Comment: Well, * or some columns, I am getting the same result with both anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `UNION` ?

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

---

**Update**: revised answer after modification of your question:

```
SELECT field1 FROM table1
UNION SELECT field2 FROM table2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

To my understanding, you just need one field from each table. If you need several ones, you can list them: field2, field2, ... as long as the number of fields is the same in both SELECTs.

---

**Update 2**: ok, I think I see what you mean now. Here is a (dirty) way to do it, I'm quite confident someone can come with a more elegant solution though:

```
SET @num1=0, @num2=0;

SELECT t1.field1, t2.field2
FROM (
    SELECT field1, @num1:=@num1+1 AS num
    FROM table1
) AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT field2, @num2:=@num2+1 AS num
    FROM (
        SELECT field2
        FROM table2
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 5
    ) AS t
) AS t2
ON t1.num = t2.num;
```

Comment: But this doesn't work with UNIONS because the two tables have different number of columns. I need a JOIN.

Comment: `UNION` does work with two heterogeneous tables, as long as the select columns count matches. It's your job to provide the same number of columns, as advised above. I think you don't understand correctly the purpose of a `JOIN`, which without a condition will simply match all records from table1 to the five records from table2, resulting in 25 records in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Try use subquery in select. **The subquery part** pick an id for each row of table1.

```sql
SELECT
  id AS table1_id,
  (
    SELECT id FROM table2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
  ) AS table2_id
FROM table1
```

The query result would be like this:

| table1_id | table2_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 36 |
| 4 | 68 |
| 5 | 5 |

You may join with table2 to select other table2 column:

```sql
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    id AS table1_id,
    (
      SELECT id FROM table2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
    ) AS table2_id
  FROM table1
) t
JOIN table1 on t.table1_id = table1.id
JOIN table2 on t.table2_id = table2.id
```